# How to find executable filetypes?

Tags: bash, files, find, executable, elf

I want to find file types that are executable from the kernel's point of view. As far as I know all the executable files on Linux are ELF files. Thus I tried the following:

`find * | file | grep ELF`

However that doesn't work; does anybody have other ideas?

Comment: @Levon It shows me the usage help of file. Probably file can't handle the input of find.

Comment: Just a small side node, with `binfmt_misc` you can run arbitrary files like classes, exes etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

Comment: @UlrichDangel: +1 for mentioning `binfmt_misc`. Binary formats are as flexible as filesystems on Linux. By all means, find ELFs, but (a) you're not finding *all* executable files, (b) the ELFs you find aren't necessarily *executable* in practice. For instance, a SPARC64 ELF won't run on an x86.

Comment: No. The a.out files are executable as well, and files marked executable like bashscripts with appropriate shebang.

Comment: Why do I get negative votes on that question, idiots at work?

Comment: Maybe because you don't correct your statement about executable files, but in the comments we can read that you're only interested in binary-elf files?

Comment: Yeah maybe, but well I'm far from beeing an expert, rather a unix beginner thus I mentioned that I was not sure if ELF was the only type of executables. It happens that a beginner can't post a question a 100% correct but rather vague just because he's a beginner.

Comment: Nobody expects you to be an expert when asking, but for question, to be useful for others, it should be selfcontained, and give all needed information. The reader shouldn't be forced to read all the spread comments. Users search for questions by keywords, phrases and decide to read it by the headline. If you don't work on your question to improve it, it is useless for others and should receive even more downvotes. If it is clarified in the question, what you're really looking for - mainly in the headline - it can be upvoted. A downvote is however locked until the question is edited.

Comment: If you improve your question, so that most of the comments get obsolete, these comments can be deleted. This improves the question even further, since there is less noise to read. Think information / noise ratio.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Later edit: only this one does what jan needs: thank you huygens;

`find . -exec file {} \; | grep -i elf`

Comment: `find . -exec file {} \; | grep -i elf` is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I think your first command doesn't work. It is searching for files with a name like "*elf *" (without taking into account the case). You want to grep the output just likeyou did in the second proposal.

Comment: @huygens I tested it before I posted and it works. touch elf 1elf 1ELF2 elf2</code> ; my command will find all the elf related files;

Comment: @huygens I tested it before I posted and it works. touch elf 1elf 1ELF2 elf2 ; my command will find all the elf related files (just like the grep); you got that error because you have copy pasted it (i think) and it has a blank space not needed, in the " " . but if I write "asteriskELFasterisk" in <code>, the html eats my asterisks!!!

Comment: If you do `cd /sbin; find . -iname "*elf*" -exec file {} \;` it will report no files :) however `cd /sbin; find . -exec file {} \; | grep -i elf` will report several. Hence my point is correct. The -iname option of find just check if the filename match the pattern. So if a ELF executable is called mkswap, you won't find it. PS: I've tried both `"*elf*"` and `*elf *"` and as I would expect no binaries are found in /sbin which is incorrect.

Comment: @huygens : you are write, my mistake. I did not understand well what ian needed, at first.

Comment: @fromnaboo no problem, you can edit and correct your post as the second part is correct. :)

Comment: i edited it, thanks (my internet connection is crappy, that's why i double post)

Comment: This will find files that contain `"elf"` in their file name.  I found that grepping for `" elf "` was good enough for my application, but in the most general case a file named `"this is not elf .txt"` would give a false positive.

Answer (score 7):

Alternate solution not using `file` and `readelf`, for those on limited (e.g. embedded) systems:

```
find $WHERE -type f -exec hexdump -n 4 -e '4/1 "%2x" " {}\n"'  {} \; | grep ^7f454c46
```

Basically, we output first four bytes with `hexdump` and use them as a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). We can then grep all the files of type [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) using its signature `7f454c46`.

Or, since `7f` is the [delete character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character), and `45`, `4c`, `46` bytes are `E`, `L`, `F` characters respectively, we could also use:

```
find $WHERE -type f -exec hexdump -n 4 -e '4/1 "%1_u" " {}\n"'  {} \; | grep ^delELF
```

Also, you can use `head` instead of `hexdump` in this case:

```
find $WHERE -type f -exec head -c 4 {} \; -exec echo " {}" \;  | grep ^.ELF
```

Comment: The `grep` command could use the `--text` flag.  Without it, some file headers have characters that will put `grep` into binary mode--which will suppress all further matches with the `grep: (standard input): binary file matches` message.

Comment: How about using `$'\x7FELF'` for the exact string to match?

Answer (score 3):

Like others, I want to answer too. My answer is based on using the `find` utility too, but I have an idea, which is differ against other answers. It grounded on that fact, that the `-exec` can be used as the search criteria too. Now, having this thing in mind, we can refactor all of the previous proposals to this one:

```
find /path -type f -exec sh -c "file {} | grep -Pi ': elf (32|64)-bit' > /dev/null" \; -print
```

I.e. we have moved the `grep` into the `-exec`.

What does this give to us, you may ask? We can use the flexibility of the `-print` and others of the `find` utility. For example, we can format an output on our taste, or use the `-print0` and redirect an output to some script etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on `-executable` flag of `find`.

Comment: That's not quite what I want, I don't want files that are tagged as executable files but I want to find ELF files, files that are recognized as executable by the kernel.

Comment: The flag executable match permissions (so directories too), see the man page: `Matches files which are executable and directories which are searchable (in a file name resolution sense).`

Comment: @Huygens: So directories are files (everything is a file on Unix), but to exclude them, just use `find -type f -executable`.

Comment: @Ian: But Shellscripts are executable by the kernel. Executable flag + appropriate shebang means executable file. Or flag + binary-elf, or flag + a.out, or flag + binfmt-patch.

Comment: @userunknown shell script aren't executable by the kernel. You need to run a shell and have the interpreter to execute them. As I understood Ian question, he is looking only for binary executable files. Thus `find -type f -executable` would not be correct as shell script would be reported. In addition if a binary does not have the x permission, this command would not detect it. Either it is wanted or not, both cases have different purpose.

Comment: @Huygens: No, you can execute shell scripts with exec-calls, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29 . If there is a shebang, only the **rest** of the script is executed by the interpreter. Since 1980.

Comment: @userunknown interesting, didn't know that.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the original question refers to [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files only (and not any other "executable from the kernel's point of view"), there is a shorter and, most likely, faster alternative to `find` + `file`:

```
$ scanelf -R /SEARCH/PATH
 TYPE   FILE 
ET_DYN /SEARCH/PATH/library.so
ET_EXEC /SEARCH/PATH/app1
ET_EXEC /SEARCH/PATH/app2
```

It recursively searches for ELF files, prints object file type and filepath for each.

Narrow the search down to only executable ELF files: `scanelf -EET_EXEC -R /SEARCH/PATH`.

Suppress banner and type, keeping only filepaths: `scanelf -EET_EXEC -RBF %F /SEARCH/PATH`.

Comment: This command is available as part of the `pax-utils` package.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for regular files first as binary executable are belonging to that type of files.

Then I would request for each regular file the mime type and if it matches application/x-executable then it is a binary executable files (that should match Linux executable files, Windows one for instance match application/x-dosexec).

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 file -i | grep "application/x-executable"
```

Trying this command I found a discrepency with `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 file | grep -w ELF`. It seems that the command `file` is buggy and detects ELF executable as ELF shared object. So even though the command is theoricaly correct, in practice it is incomplete.

So we have to look for ELF executables and shared objects but exclude all files with a name of *.so and *.so.*

```
find . -type f ! \( -name "*.so.*" -o -name "*.so" \) -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 file -i | egrep "application\/x-sharedlib|application\/x-executable"
```

It is not probably perfect, but that's the pretty close.

Comment: Actually my first answer is not fully correct, as some binary executable files are detected by `file -i` as application/x-sharedlib and not application/x-executable.

Comment: The binaries I sampled from my Mac are `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`, according to both the Mac's `file` and the `file` on my Debian box. (Speaking of OS X, the `file` it includes uses `-I` instead of `-i`. Both accept `--mime`, though.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers the original question if their intent was to find binary executable files by ensuring each match has an elf header.

It sort of pre-processes files based on type `-executable` then runs the results through a separate shell that invokes `readelf -l` which pipes to grep which silently matches on headers that are explicitly `executable`. Anything that passes this test is passed to `printf` for the output.

The `pwd` bit outputs the full path.

```
find `pwd` -type f -executable -exec sh -c 'readelf -l "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -qio 'executable' && printf "$1\n"' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
find . -type f -executable -exec sh -c "[[ \"\$(head -c 4 -- \"\${1}\")\" == \$'\\x7FELF' ]]" -- \{\} \; -print
```

has the advantage that it doesn't "escape `find`". Instead of the final `-print` (or after it) you can add other filters or commands while still acting within the `find`.

The part

```bsh
-exec sh -c "[[ \"\$(head -c 4 -- \"\${1}\")\" == \$'\\x7FELF' ]]" -- \{\} \;
```

acts as a filter in the `find`, discarding files that do not start with the ELF file marker.

I'm not sure if the

```bsh
-type f -executable
```

part is truly needed, especially both conditions at once. But I *guess* in large trees it might be faster to discard the paths first based on the elementary properties, before trying to read them.

In my particular use case (that lead me here) I was trying to capture some basing ELF data of all executables generated by a build. However, the tree contained also other (non-ELF) executable files, like for example shell scripts. That caused `readelf` to fail and break the `find`. Adding the filter to discard non-ELF files first resolved the problem. For completeness, my full command was:

```bsh
find . -type f -executable -exec sh -c "[[ \"\$(head -c 4 -- \"\${1}\")\" == \$'\\x7FELF' ]]" -- \{\} \; -print -exec readelf -d -- \{\} \;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
find -type f -exec file {} \; | grep ELF | grep executable | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Doesn't work on all files/paths