# Less specific input for script

Tags: bash, scripting, input

Some time ago while i was searching for a way to find out what i can delete from my Android rom without crippling functions i use, i found `deptree` over at the `xda forums`. Since this was written back in 2012 it wouldn't work as intended. Updating used tools (`dex2jar`, `smali`, `...`) plus some minor changes to the scripts (like changing folders to the ones used in `Android` by now, for example `system/app-private` to `system/priv-app/*/`) and i got it running again.
Part of the magic happens in three scripts which are similar to this one:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    for bin in "$1"/*; do
        [ -f "$bin" ] || continue
        case "$bin" in
            *.so)
            ;;
            *)
            [ -x "$bin" ] || continue
            ;;
        esac
        "$FILE_DIR/perls/parse_bin.pl" "$bin" dbi:SQLite:dbname="$ACTIVE_DB/test.sqlite" 2>>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
    done
shift
done
```

Through using my superpowers of having never learned to code, i concluded following things to happen here (you may correct me if i got something wrong):

1. while accessing the input folder `$1`,
2. every `bin(ary)` file gets
3. checked if it really is a `binary`file, if so,
   ( i have no idea what the `||`stands for)
4. it checks for the extension (`.so`or `none`) and
5. uses the file(s) found (`*.so` and the ones without extension) as input for the script `parse_bin.pl`

The input folder has to be super specific, as for this script these are

```
$ACTIVE_DB/rom/system/lib $ACTIVE_DB/rom/system/lib/*/ $ACTIVE_DB/rom/system/usr/lib you get how this continues, super long list of folders
```

What i'd like to know, how would i have to modify these three scripts so that the input folder is `$ACTIVE_DB/rom/system`?

EDIT: The mechanism of finding the file(s) in the input folder(s) is the same in all three scripts except that the other two are searching for `*.jar` and `*.apk`

EDIT2: The `bash` shell gets used to run this

I know this has to happen somewhere in the first two lines of the script, i already tried `fromnaboo`s answer from over [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40063/how-to-find-executable-filetypes) which would spit out every binary inside the folder `$ACTIVE_DB/rom` but would not pass them as input to `parse_bin.pl`.

Please have a log:

```
+ PARSE_BIN DB_45763/rom/system
+ '[' -n DB_45763/rom/system ']'
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/CSCVersion.txt ']'
+ case "$bin" in
+ '[' -x DB_45763/rom/system/CSCVersion.txt ']'
+ printf 'DB_45763/rom/system/CSCVersion.txt:\t'
+ echo DB_45763/rom/system/CSCVersion.txt
+ ./files/perls/parse_bin.pl DB_45763/rom/system/CSCVersion.txt dbi:SQLite:dbname=DB_45763/test.sqlite
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/app ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/bin ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/build.prop ']'
+ case "$bin" in
+ '[' -x DB_45763/rom/system/build.prop ']'
+ printf 'DB_45763/rom/system/build.prop:\t'
+ echo DB_45763/rom/system/build.prop
+ ./files/perls/parse_bin.pl DB_45763/rom/system/build.prop dbi:SQLite:dbname=DB_45763/test.sqlite
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/cameradata ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/csc ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/csc_contents ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/etc ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/fonts ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/framework ']'
+ continue
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/kern_sec_info ']'
+ case "$bin" in
+ '[' -x DB_45763/rom/system/kern_sec_info ']'
+ printf 'DB_45763/rom/system/kern_sec_info:\t'
+ echo DB_45763/rom/system/kern_sec_info
+ ./files/perls/parse_bin.pl DB_45763/rom/system/kern_sec_info dbi:SQLite:dbname=DB_45763/test.sqlite
+ for bin in '"$1"/*'
+ '[' -f DB_45763/rom/system/lib ']'
+ continue
+ shift
+ '[' -n '' ']'
```

Comment: This script firstly checks if the current iteration of `$bin` is a regular file, if not the `|| continue` expression is saying go back to the start of the loop and  begin with a new `$bin`. What shell is being used to run this script?

Comment: Thanks for the info on `||` , the `bash` shell gets used to run this. I've added this info to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your assumption of what the script does seems correct. 
It looks at all the files, folders, symlinks etc that it finds in `$1`, if its a file, then it drills down deeper to determine if its a library or an executable.

In shell scripting `$1` is the first argument passed to the script, so to run this script with `$ACTIVE_DB/rom/system` in the position of `$1` you would simply invoke the script with

```
./scriptname $ACTIVE_DB/rom/system
```

Note: If you are calling this from a command prompt `$ACTIVE` will have to be substituted for the actual path.

In order to make this script descend recursively into your target directory you could try adding this to your script

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    # use globbing to descend into all subdirectories
    for bin in $(find "$1" | tr '\n' ' '); do
    # change this  ^^^^   
        [ -f "$bin" ] || continue
        # leave the rest of the script as is
        # ....
```

Comment: I tried using `$ACTIVE_DB/rom/system` before, but this won't work. As far as i can see the problem is, that the script does not search recursively (?), it just checks the files in `$ACTIVE_DB/rom/system` and not the ones in the subdirectories or at least is unable to find files inside them (see the log). Thanks for the testing advice, it's all i do by now^^ I've added the log for what happens when using `$ACTIVE_DB/rom/system` as input.

Comment: @chris Ive updated my answer to descend into subdirectories

Comment: I don't know what's up with me today, like my brain use only 1/3, i should have noted i'm on `OS X` here. `globstar` is not available. Did a quick search and installed `bash 4` from `brew` (`brew install bash`) where this should work but it won't (and yes, i added `bash 4` to `/etc/shells` and run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash YOUR_USER_NAME`. `echo $BASH_VERSION` prints out `4.3.42(1)-release`). Seems to be about time for a coffee to kickstart the brain

Comment: Ok Ive updated, this  `$(find  "$1")` substitution will descend recursively , but it will also return a newline delimited string so Im not sure how the for loop will handle it - I suspect it will actually break...

Comment: Super awesome, this works. But it also uses found `*.apk` as input for `parse_bin.pl`. I think i'm gonna try to combine the three scripts, so that found `*.apk` and `*.jar` get used as input for `parse_apk.pl` and `parse_jar.pl`

Comment: Ok I just added `$(find "$1" | tr '\n' ' ')` in case the previous find substitution didnt work with the for loop, but if it did cool

Comment: Tried this new addition, works the same as far as i can judge. Anyways, get the upvote and accepted answer^^ thanks for your help

Comment: cool, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyones wondering what i did, here's the code as of now.
Thanks @the_velour_fog for helping me.
If anyone thinks this is the worst possible solution
(i don't think it's super sexy either but it does what it has to do) get em here.

```
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    for bin in $(find "$1"); do
        [ -f "$bin" ] || continue
        case "$bin" in
            *.so)
                export start=$(date +"%T")
                printf "$bin:\t"
                echo -n "$start  " >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                echo "$bin" >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                "$FILE_DIR/perls/parse_bin.pl" "$bin" dbi:SQLite:dbname="$ACTIVE_DB/test.sqlite" 2>>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                ;;
            *.jar)
                export start=$(date +"%T")
                printf "$bin:\t"
                echo -n "$start  " >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_jar.log"
                echo "$bin" >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_jar.log"
                "$FILE_DIR/perls/parse_jar.pl" "$bin" dbi:SQLite:dbname="$ACTIVE_DB/test.sqlite" 2>>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_jar.log"
                ;;
            *.apk)
                export start=$(date +"%T")
                printf "$bin:\t"
                echo -n "$start  " >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_apk.log"
                echo "$bin" >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_apk.log"
                "$FILE_DIR/perls/parse_apk.pl" "$bin" dbi:SQLite:dbname="$ACTIVE_DB/test.sqlite" 2>>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_apk.log"
                ;;
            *)
                if [ -x "$bin" ] ; then
                    export start=$(date +"%T")
                    printf "$bin:\t"
                    echo -n "$start  " >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                    echo "$bin" >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                    "$FILE_DIR/perls/parse_bin.pl" "$bin" dbi:SQLite:dbname="$ACTIVE_DB/test.sqlite" 2>>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                else
                    continue
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    done
shift
done
```

As far as i can see for now, this works, but i'm quite unsure about this part at the end

```
     *)
            if [ -x "$bin" ] ; then
                export start=$(date +"%T")
                printf "$bin:\t"
                echo -n "$start  " >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                echo "$bin" >>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
                "$FILE_DIR/perls/parse_bin.pl" "$bin" dbi:SQLite:dbname="$ACTIVE_DB/test.sqlite" 2>>"$ACTIVE_DB/logs/parse_bin.log"
            else
                continue
            fi
```

The future will show^^